# Different between two type of adapter syntax in android

Tags: android, syntax, android-adapter

Model One :

```
private Context mContext;
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = inflater.inflate("layout name",parent, false); 
}
```

Model Two:

```
private Context mContext;
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = inflater.inflate("layout name", null); 
}
```

Difference between the two snippets:

`convertView = inflater.inflate("layout name" , null);`

and

`convertView = inflater.inflate("layout name", parent, false);`

Comment: press Ctrl button on your keyboard and then click on inflate method. It will take you into the super class. There you can read about all the methods available in that class alongwith description

Comment: I think you just need to look at this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**inflate with 2 prams**:
`inflate(int resource, ViewGroup root)`

**inflate with 3 prams**:
`inflate(int resource, ViewGroup root, boolean attachToRoot)`

**resource:** int: ID for an XML layout resource to load (e.g., R.layout.main_page)

**root:** ViewGroup: Optional view to be the parent of the generated hierarchy (if attachToRoot is true), or else simply an object that provides a set of LayoutParams values for root of the returned hierarchy (if attachToRoot is false.)

**attachToRoot:**  boolean: Whether the inflated hierarchy should be attached to the root parameter? If false, root is only used to create the correct subclass of LayoutParams for the root view in the XML.

[**See Android Docs.**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html)

Comment: have you understand.

Comment: 1.inflate(int resource, ViewGroup root)                                                    2.inflate(int resource, ViewGroup root, boolean attachToRoot)                             ViewGroup is accepting null value but Android studio shows some warning for giving  "null"  value to ViewGroup ( "Avoid passing null as the view root (needed to resolve layout  parameters on the inflated layout's root element) ")

Comment: its a Optional view to be the parent of the generated hierarchy.if you use only one view then pass null and if you multiple view in hierarchy then you make this newly generated view as parent of this view by passing it as parameter.Hope you understand.if it help please consider vote up or tick mark.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that you can specify a parent element for the inflated layout and can control whether or not the inflated layout should be attached to the parent. You can find the documentation of [LayoutInflaters here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html).

Btw. You can use a more readable syntax like this one:

```
final View viewToAdd = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(layoutId, null);
```